# Wordpress как грузить картинки из внешних ссылок не сохраняя

Tags: wordpress, url, изображения, upload

Здраствуйте, как можно прикрепить картинку к миниатюре поста wordpress например, которая подгружается с другого сайта, то есть не загружая ее в папку, а показывая по внешнему url?

Comment: Вы используете Classic Editor или Gutenberg?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/external+media/